# Can't seem to move or duplicate a mesh as expected in Object mode. What on earth have I done?

Tags: modeling, objects, select

Ok I don't know if I'll explain this properly. I have no idea what I've selected to make this happen but it's messing with my head.

In my current project I cannot move a mesh in Object mode, I need to be in edit mode. If I duplicate in object mode using shift D it seems to add a new mesh, but I can only move the visible Move icon. I have no idea what this is option/function is for. See image below:
[image]

If a create a new project with a mesh, I can move the mesh by pressing G. Or when I press shift D it immediately moves the duplicated mesh and can be moved as below:
[image]

What on earth have I done? I've searched through all the menus I can think of I don't know what option I've selected to make this happen, but I don't like it. Appreciate any help with this.

Comment: You may have changed keymaps you can go in user preferences>keymap and then select blender 2.8x from drop-down menu, or you can just factory reset the whole thing.

Comment: Hello :). You probably enabled Origins Transform in *Sidebar > Tool > Options*. Shortcut is `Ctrl`+`.` to toggle on/off.

Comment: @Jachym Michal that's exactly what it was, thank you!!